# Woocommarce Product item to buy multiple items, get 10% off the lowest-priced item

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

woocommarce custom functionality for setup discount on Woocommerce Product to buy 2 items and get 10% off on lower priced item or buy multiple items , get 10% off the lowest-priced item?